# HTTP Caching Headers: private vs no-cache

Tags: http, http-proxy, caching

We're currently reviewing our set of "no-cache" security headers:

- *`Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`*
- *`Pragma "no-cache"`*
- *`Expires 0`*

Besides the "standard" set above, I found [this article](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/The+Security+Impact+of+HTTP+Caching+Headers/17033/), recommending to combine "no-cache" and "no-store" with "private".  As far as I understand [the specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) it should be sufficient to set "no-cache" and "no-store" if you want to forbid caching at all.

So my question: **Are there any reasons to add the "private" header to our set?  And if so, will there be a conflict between the headers?**

P.S.: I also checked the following two discussions, which did not provide a definite answer.

- ["Cache-control: private" vs. "Cache-control: no-cache"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Issues/cache-private.html)
- [Making sure a web page is not cached, across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Comment: This article (in particular the flow chart) might be of interest to you: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: [`private` applies to HTTP 1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234). Private is used if you don't mind the content being stored in the browser cache, but do not want it being stored in shared caches (e.g. proxy servers). HTTP 1.0 had `pragma` in the request and `expires` in the response.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3492459/6381711) is quite elaborate and answers it all.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the *contradiction* (if we may call it so) you highlighted. So I read both (some parts of the specification related to the *private* option) and the article.

I rather searched about the [original article](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T55032) where the bug was first mentioned. In that article, it is stated:

> It was reported that multiple meta.wikimedia.org users received the
>   same session ID. These users could act as the user who happened to be
>   logged in according to the session value.

So you can conclude there is nothing wrong with the specification, and you need to add the `private` option  in `Cache-control` **only when there is a session**.